# JS creating different accounts with one instance

Tags: javascript, class, object

I was searching for an answer but could not find the right one. Thats why I give it a try:

The last console.log() in my code is obviously printing 700 because with the code you can't recognize what person is doing a deposit. 
Of course I could create different instances like 
let bank1 = new Bank() <-- this could be Mia 
let bank2 = new Bank() <-- this could be Lio.

But is there a way with just one instance?

Here is my code:

```
    function Bank (customer) {
        this.customer ={
            name: "",
            account: 0
        }

    Bank.prototype.addCustomer = function (customer){
        this.customer["name"] = customer; 
    }

    Bank.prototype.printAccount = function (customer){
        console.log(`${customer}'s account is ${this.customer["account"]}`)
    }

    Bank.prototype.deposit = function (customer, amount){
       this.customer["name"] = customer; 
       this.customer["account"]+= amount; 
    }

    let bank = new Bank(); 

    console.log(bank.deposit("Mia", 300)); 
    console.log(bank.printAccount("Mia"));
    console.log(bank.deposit("Lio", 400)); 
    console.log(bank.printAccount("Lio"));

// this last log prints obviously 700 because I can't tell my code to "recognize" the different people.
```

Thank you so much for your help and sorry if this might sound like a stupid question but I just started with this creepy classes :-)

Comment: Might want `this.customer` to be an array or object with each customer set as a unique id key , that way you can have multiple customers. eg `this.customer.push({...})` and `this.customer[0]['name']='Lio`, `this.customer[1]['name']='Mia'` etc

Comment: Make an `Account` class and use multiple instances of it.